# Is it possible to optimize my js hashmap challenge to merge two .forEach loops?

Tags: javascript, optimization

Is it possible to merge the two arr.forEach() functions in my code together?

Here is my code:

```
function countTriplets(arr, r) {
    let count = 0;
    let freq = {};
    let arrSum = [];
    
    arr.forEach((num) => {
        freq[num] ? freq[num]++ : freq[num] = 1;
    })
    
    arr.forEach((number) => {
        let sum = freq[number/r] * freq[number * r];
        if(!isNaN(sum)) {
            arrSum.push(sum);
        }
    });
    console.log("freq", freq);
    console.log("arrSum", arrSum);
    count = arrSum.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    return count;
        
}
```

If you are wondering what my code is about. It's to count the amount of triplets in an array such as `[1, 5, 5, 25, 125]`. It's for HackerRank challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-triplets-1/problem.
The main challenge posted in this link is:

> You are given an array and you need to find number of tripets of
> indices **(i, j, k)** such that the elements at those indices are in
> geometric progression for a given common ratio **r** and **i < j < k**
> .
>
> For example, **arr = [1, 4, 16, 64]** . If **r = 4**, we have **[1, 4,
> 16]**  and **[4, 16, 64]**.

I got my solution/inspiration from watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBFZMaWP0W8.

Comment: Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: I tried, but it's because I asked to check the next number in the freq array, it didn't work. But I still wonder if it's still possible

Comment: It would help if you would describe the purpose of the code (in your question)

Comment: Please add an example of how you are calling this.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to count the amount of triplets in an array such as [1,5, 5, 25, 125]. In this case, the count is 4.

Comment: @KristinaBressler What is a "triplet"? And what is `r`?

Comment: The relevant information should not be behind a link. For instance, it is relevant what the range of `r` is: apparently it can be 1. Your code is not right in the case `r=1`.

Comment: @Bergi  I just updated my question with more information

Comment: @KristinaBressler Ah, now it makes more sense.

Comment: Critical question... is the assumption that the array is in progressively increasing order?  Eg, seems that `[1,16,4,64]` should return 0, but the OP's solution returns 2...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [@Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65962692/3113485), you can't combine the two for loops.

But I believe you can eliminate this step:

```js
count = arrSum.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Here's a version of the [algorithm in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65962407/3113485) that eliminates the final `arrSum.reduce` and uses `reduce` in place of `forEach`.

```js
function countTriplets(arr, r) {
  const freq = arr.reduce((freq, num) => {
    freq[num] = freq[num] ? freq[num] + 1 : 1;
    return freq;
  }, {});
  console.log('freq', freq);

  const count = arr.reduce((sum, number) => {
    const triplets =
      freq[number / r] && freq[number * r]
        ? freq[number / r] * freq[number * r]
        : 0;
    return sum + triplets;
  }, 0);
  return count;
}

const arr = [1, 5, 5, 25, 125];

const count = countTriplets(arr, 5);
console.log(`count:`, count);
```

There's also the case where `r == 1`. That's a faster calculation, as the triplet count for each number is just the [combinations formula](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php):

```sh
                freq!          freq * (freq-1) * (freq-2)
triplets = ---------------- = ----------------------------
            3! * (freq-3)!                6
```

Where `n!` means `factorial of n`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the last formula where the r  is 1. In case if arr is [1,1,1,1,1], then the freq is 5, right? So for the triplets formula, should it be (5 / (3 * 2))?

Comment: @KristinaBressler No, for a freq of 5, the r=1 formula is `5! / (3! * 2!)`, which is `120 / (6 * 2)`, or 10.  The exclamation point stands for "factorial".

Comment: oh thanks! I thought that "!" means that it removes `null` and `undefined` from the freq array.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to merge the two `arr.forEach()` functions in my code together?

No. The algorithm relies on all the counts being computed first and evaluated second.

> Is it possible to optimize my solution by merging two loops?

No. You won't achieve a better time complexity by merging them, it's still a linear solution (which is as good as it gets).

If you want to improve your code, I'd suggest to

- use a `Map` instead of an object, it's better suited for this purpose
- don't use `isNaN` to determine whether a key exists in your map
- deal with edge case `r=1` correctly (as mentioned by @trincot in the comments)
- deal with edge case `arr=[]` correctly (the `reduce` doesn't work without an initial value)

To further improve the speed of your code, do some benchmarking. Apart from switching to a `Map`, try changing the `forEach` call to a `for … of` or `for(let i=0; i<….length; i++)` loop, and don't keep the individual counts in a temporary `arrSum` array but just directly sum them (`count += sum`). Run the benchmarks with inputs of different sizes and different triplet distributions.